# $this->getChildHtml() returns empty string

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to insert a `div` inside the `list.phtml` file at `app/design/frontend/[custom]/[theme]/template/catalog/product` using `$this->getChildHtml()`.

When doing `<?php var_dump( $this->getChildHtml('odoo') )?>` i get `string(0) ""`

I have created a module at `app/code/local/[Company]/[Module]` and created the `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>  
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules> 
    <frontend>
        <rwd>
            <company>
                <layout>
                    <odoo>
                        <file>odoo.xml</file>
                    </odoo>
                </layout>
            </company>
        </rwd>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then, inside `app/design/frontend/[custom]/[theme]/layout/odoo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="odoo" template="catalog/product/odoo.phtml" as="odoo" />
        </reference>
</layout>
```

The code of `odoo.phtml`:

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Inside `list.phtml`

```
<?php var_dump( $this->getChildHtml('odoo') )?>
```

I've cleared the cache and manually erased the `full_page_cache` contents but i think i'm doing somethign wrong. I have little experience with Magento, mostry just editing the frontend, so i'm a little lost here.

Comment: Can you var_dump one level higher? It seems that the `getChildHtml` attribute of `$this` has no `odoo` tag.

Comment: var_dump( $this )

Comment: @phillipstack The result was a empty page. Looks like it generated an aerror but looking at system.log, there is no error.

Comment: You need to work your way up the chain. It would seem $this has no content in it. Locate wherever $this is assigned and see what is used to define its value. Do var_dump on its components as well.

Comment: `$this` is not empty because i use it to get the products to display `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` so it may be another issue

Comment: The contents of your var_dump are html. As a result they are being rendered and not displayed by your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Added `<block type="core/template" name="odoo" template="catalog/product/odoo.phtml" as="odoo" />` to the `page.xml` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `var_dump()` with html you can see. Then use your browser and inspect the elements. The contents are probably inside. If you `var_dump()` html. You will not see the string representation of the html. The html just becomes part of the page you are viewing.

Try this.

```
<div style="background-color: blue; height:30px;"/>
    <?php var_dump( $this ) ?>
<div style="background-color: blue; height:30px;"/>
```

If you right click and inspect the elements and navigate through the html in your debugger you will find the contents of `$this`. You should then be able to determine if the tags you are looking for are inside or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below i hope its working for you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
             <reference name="product.info">
                    <block type="core/template" name="odoo" template="catalog/product/odoo.phtml" as="odoo" />
            </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Also if still showing empty then try to change block to type from core/template to your block name.